# What is the correct way to setup my virtual hosts in Apache to serve 2 differnt domains?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a current website on an Apache server (foo.com) and I want the same server to serve a new site (bar.com), is this the correct way to setup my virtual hosts?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.com
    ServerAlias www.foo.com
    Include conf.d/foo.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bar.com
    ServerAlias www.bar.com
    Include conf.d/bar.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm hesitant to do an /etc/init.d/httpd reload without someone double checking! :)

Comment: I am assuming you have a `NameVirtualHost` somewhere in your configuration already?

Answer (score 3):

That looks correct ! You can also always run

```
 apache2ctl configtest
```

to make sure the apache config syntax is correct